# Remove an object from an ArrayList given only one attribute

Tags: java, object, arraylist, casting

I have an ArrayList of Items and I want to be able remove one Item from the list by entering only one Item attribute, for example its number (int ItemNumber). I also wanna do the same when I check Item quantities.

These are my  `equals()` & `contains()` methods, do I need to make any changes here?

```
public boolean contains(T anEntry) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int index = 0; !found && (index < numberOfEntries); index++) {
    if (anEntry.equals(list[index])) 
        found = true;
    }//end for
    return found;
} // end contains

public boolean equals(Object object){
    Item item = (Item) object;
    if (itemNo == item.itemNo)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you want to look at using a Map rather than a List

Comment: Sorry, but I don't even get where that code comes from. Is is the class that contains the item (in a list)? Then why overwrite equals there? Or did you put two methods from different classes in the same code block here? Confusing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you change the class `Item` `equals()` and `compareTo()` methods, so that they check only one object field, such as a `quantity`, it could result in strange behavior in other parts of your application. For example, two items with different `itemNo`, `itemName`, and `itemPrice`, but with the same quantities could be considered equal. Besides, you wouldn't be able to change the comparison attribute without changing the `equals()` code every time.

Also, creating a custom `contains()` method makes no sense, since it belongs to the `ArrayList` class, and not to `Item`.

**If you can use Java 8**, a clean way to do it is to use the new `Collection`'s [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

Suppose you have an `Item` class with the `num` and `name` properties:

```
class Item {
    final int num;
    final String name;

    Item(int num, String name) {
        this.num = num;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Given a `List<Item>` called `items` and an `int` variable called `number`, representing the number of the item you want to remove, you could simply do:

```
items.removeIf(item -> item.num == number);
```

**If you are unable to use Java 8**, you can achieve this by using custom comparators, binary search, and dummy objects.

You can create a custom comparator for each attribute you need to look for. The comparator for `num` would look like this:

```
class ItemNumComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item a, Item b) {
        return (a.num < b.num) ? -1 : ((a.num == b.num) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the comparator to sort and search for the desired elements in your list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new Item(2, "ball"));
    items.add(new Item(5, "cow"));
    items.add(new Item(3, "gum"));

    Comparator<Item> itemNumComparator = new ItemNumComparator();
    Collections.sort(items, itemNumComparator);

    // Pass a dummy object containing only the relevant attribute to be searched
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(items, new Item(5, ""), itemNumComparator);
    Item removedItem = null;
    // binarySearch will return -1 if it does not find the element.
    if (index > -1) {
        // This will remove the element, Item(5, "cow") in this case, from the list
        removedItem = items.remove(index);
    }
    System.out.println(removedItem);
}
```

To search for another field like name, for example, you would need to create a name comparator and use it to sort and run the binary search on your list.

Note this solution has some drawbacks though. Unless you are completely sure that the list didn't change since the last sort, you **must** re-sort it before running the `binarySearch()` method. Otherwise, it may not be able to find the correct element. Sorting complexity is `O(nlogn)`, so running it multiple times can get quite expensive depending on the size of your list.

Comment: It's not working :( I think there's a problem with the separate class Can I somehow implement a method called CompareTo that would work with my contains() and equals() methods mentioned above?

Comment: What's the problem you're getting? A compareTo and an equals method that only check one attribute may result in strange behavior in other parts of the code that use the Item objects.

Comment: What kind of strange behavior? What would the idea of the compareTo method be? I will try it out. with this, I'm having a problem in the Class itself I'm getting this error: "The method compare(int, int) is undefined for the type Integer"

Comment: The problem is that you are probably using Java 6, and it doesn't have the Integer.compare() method. I updated the answer, please try using the compare() method now. I also explained the problems of changing equals() to check just one attribute. The compareTo() method would be almost the same as the compare() method above, but it would be implemented in the Item class and accept just one Item object as parameter.

Comment: This would work, but I don't think I'm supposed to implement a separate class for this .. I have to implement all my methods in an ArrayList class that would work for any type, in my case it's Items. that's why I'm trying to implement the compareTo

Comment: The compareTo() will be almost the same as the compare() method, but its signature would be compareTo(Item other). It needs to be implemented in the Item class, and Item must implement interface Comparable<Item>.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how to implement this CompareTo() method. Because I will also need it later for another method called "checkquantity ( int limit)" that will move the Item with quantity less than limit to the front of the list. I just can't think of a correct way to implement CompareTo() since I don't have a good background in java :(

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to remove an object at a specific index? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'number field'. If so, jump to method: remove(int):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29

EDIT: If you want to find/adjust a field of an object in the Array list, you can do this (piece of my own code):

```
public boolean studentHasISBN(ArrayList<Student> st, String s){
    for(Student j : st) {
        if(s.equals(j.getRentedBookISBN()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

All you have to do is iterate through the list, and search through the field that you want to find. Then use the remove(int) method.

Comment: I have a class Items with the follwing Attributes 
(ItemNumber, ItemName, ItemPrice, Quantity) I want to remove the who Item using only the ItemNumber attribute, how is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

simply use the `remove` function of `ArrayLists` in `Java`:

```
theNameOfYourArrayList.remove(ItemNumber);
```

to remove the element which has the index `(int ItemNumber)`

to check if the element with item number `(int ItemNumber)`  exists in your `ArrayList` (hypothetically called `theNameOfYourArrayList`):

```
theNameOfYourArrayList.get(ItemNumber);
```

Comment: And how do I check if this ItemNumber exists at all in my list?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that by 'number field' you mean that you invoked ArrayList with the Integer data type. I have a few different solutions to your problem:

1. ArrayLists, assuming that the ArrayList is `ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();` you can simply write a method that will search 'numList' and delete the index that the number is. The problem is, contains and find in ArrayLists can be slow.

   `public void deleteNumField(int field) {
       // this will stop any error if field isn't actually in numList
       // and it will remove the first index of field in the ArrayList
       if(numList.contains(field)) numList.remove(numList.find(field));
   }`
2. HashSets, HashSets are a handy data type that is like an ArrayList, except, its data is its 'index' (sortof). I won't go in depth about how they work, but I will say that searching in them is considered O(1). This will make your deletion really easy, and fast. Note: the HashSet assumes there are no duplicate numbers, if there are use a HashMap.

   `HashSet<Integer> numList = new HashSet<Integer>();
    public void deleteNumField(int field) {
        // this will stop errors from attempting to remove a
        // non-existant element, and remove it if it exists.
        if(numList.contains(field)) numList.remove(field);
    }`

---

For more information on HashMaps, HashSets and ArrayLists, see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/